# Meaning of "get the swing of it."

Tags: meaning, idioms

In the film "Falling Down":

Foster: Good! Good, freedom of religion. **Now you get the swing of it**. Feels good to exercise your rights, doesn't it? (opens fire).

What is D-fens try to say?

Comment: swing - a state of steady vigorous action that is characteristic of an activity; "the party went with a swing"; "it took time to get into the swing of things" http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get+back+into+the+swing+of+things

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/swing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "get the swing of it" means to understand something, to be able to do it, etc. after some learning or attempt.

For example, suppose it is your first time playing cards. At first, it is confusing and difficult, but you learn, and eventually **you get the swing of it** and you are able to play as well as the others.

Comment: -1 What is the source of this "definition"?

Comment: @Kris Your -1 would only be warranted if I were wrong, and I'm not wrong. My (informal) definition illustrates the meaning and the correct use of the phrase in question.

Comment: Please see my comment at OP^. The down vote is for the answer being inaccurate/ inadequate. You still have +8 so cheer up!

Comment: Thanks Newb. Your help is very positive. I love it. By the way, I am very disappoint why some people just post the dictionary, and even some peoples vote to closed this question..... If I can get the answer from Dictionary, why I posting it here? I feel it like some kind of idiom or slang, and cannot get a reasonable answer from Dict, when seeing the Movie, that why I ask question here. Sorry I am not native english speaker, but I feel disappoint some peoples closed this question and give me DICT. Again, Thanks Newb. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [non-standard variant on an established idiomatic usage:](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get%20the%20hang%20of%20it,get%20the%20swing%20of%20it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,get%20the%20hang%20of%20it;,c0;.t1;,get%20the%20swing%20of%20it;,c0)

[image]

From [Collins English Dictionary:](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-the-hang-of)

> **get the hang of** (informal)
>    1: *to understand the technique of doing something*
>    2: *to perceive the meaning or significance of*

Conceptually it's very similar to the (usually, more literal) usage...

> [get the **heft** of something](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22asked%20actually%20we%20do%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22get%20the%20heft%20of%22&start=0&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099)
>    [**heft**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heft) *- weight or heaviness; importance or influence*

The *heft* specifically alludes to the heaviness of something you might wield (often, a *tool*), where the *hang* more generally reference *the way it's poised, balanced*. Knowing these things implies familiarity with the object/technique, so you can handle/use/control it easily and effectively.